# How can I render the input with type='text' in blazor server-side?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor

Here are the codes:

```
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="@SubmitText" id="inputText">
            <InputText @bind-Value="_InputMsgModel.Msg" />
</EditForm>
```

After the program ran, it turned out to be this:

```
<form id="inputText">
<input class="valid">
</form>
```

Now I wanna add an attribute `type="text"` to the input element, how can I achieve this?

I tried to modify the code like this:

```
<EditForm OnValidSubmit="@SubmitText" id="inputText">
            <input type="text" @bind-Value="_InputMsgModel.Msg" />
</EditForm>
```

Meanwhile, now visual studio reports an error:
[image]

I can not bind the model anymore.

I need to set the type to text for needing to set the keyboard in mobile correctly.

How can I solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is wrong with this code:

```
<EditForm  Model="@_InputMsgModel" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitText" id="inputText" >
    <InputText  @bind-Value="@_InputMsgModel.Msg" />
</EditForm>
```

Run this code with the above:

```
@code {

InputMsgModel _InputMsgModel = new InputMsgModel();

    private void SubmitText()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_InputMsgModel.Msg);
    }



    public class InputMsgModel
    {
        public string Msg { get; set; } = "My new message";
    }
}
```

Do you see the text "My new message" in the text box ? I believe you do... All is well, and the two-way binding mechanism works well. Go and see now the Html...it's still `<input class="valid">` which does not reflect the real state of the text box. Think about it...

Update: Of course you can use the following:

```
<EditForm  Model="@_InputMsgModel" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitText" id="inputText" >
    <input type="text"  @bind-value="@_InputMsgModel.Msg" />
</EditForm>
```

Important: The error "The attribute names could not..." is triggered because you use capital "V" in `@bind-Value`. You should use lower case: `@bind-value`. This is because your using input 'Html element' here, and it has a **value** attribute, not a **Value** attribute. But when you use the InputText **Component**, the capital Value in `@bind-Value` refers to a Value property defined in the component.

Comment: Well, it works. And also I found another strange way to achieve this:<EditForm  Model="@_InputMsgModel" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitText" id="inputText" >
    <InputText  @bind-Value="@_InputMsgModel.Msg" type="text" />
</EditForm>